# swift - How to disable clicked history on iOS tableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm working on a project, an I have a menu implemented with a UITableView, until here all correct, but when i change 2 times of screen on my navigation controller it seems to not work properly.

It's like it has a history of clicked cells.

[image: Selected cells]

I've already done this to all the cells of the table view.

```
  let backgroundView = UIView()
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Primary")
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView
        cell.backgroundView = backgroundView
        cell.isSelected = false
```

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something you can do in your custom table view cell class is to override the isSelected and isHighlighted properties so as to have the colors that you want.

```
override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        backgroundColor = clearColor
    }
}

override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        backgroundColor = isHighlighted ? highlightedColor : clearColor
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped. Thanks for the upvote and accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

In the [`tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614877-tableview) delegate method for your table view, you should call [`deselectRow(at:animated:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614989-deselectrow) method as the first thing to be done:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    // ...
}
```